# Java Reg Expression to wrap HTML tag around text

Tags: java

I'm working on a text to HTML parser. I'm using the "@@" notation to mark a Bold character. Ex.

```
Example @@Bold text in a paragraph
```

Turns to:

```
Example <strong>Bold</strong> text in paragraph
```

The following code works, however I've found out that it works just on the last Bold notation found:

```
private static String escapeBold(String sCurrentLine) {
    if (sCurrentLine.indexOf("@@") < 0) {
        return sCurrentLine;
    }

    String newString = null;
    String oldString = null;
    String chars[] = sCurrentLine.split(" ");
    for (String s : chars) {
        if (s.startsWith("@@")) {
            newString = "<strong>" + s.replaceAll("@@", "") + "</strong>";
            oldString = s;
        }
    }
    return (sCurrentLine.replaceAll(oldString, newString));
}
```

Is there a simpler way to do it, maybe with a RegExpr ?
Thanks!

Comment: To use as a reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/460557

Comment: Only the first? Not the last?

Comment: My mistake- it parses only the last! I have corrected the question

Comment: @JorgeCampos not really relevant here...

Comment: @Jorge Campos No, he is not parsing html. He is adding html tags to a parsed string. Its getting annoying how people link to that question every time html and regex is in the same sentence.

Comment: You can use replaceAll: template.replaceAll("@@([^\\s]+)", "<strong>$1</strong>");

Comment: @maksim07 `[^\\s]` can be written as `\\S` (I also included this in my answer, hope you don't mind).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your method can look like

```
private static String escapeBold(String sCurrentLine) {
    return sCurrentLine.replaceAll("@@(\\w+)", "<strong>$1</strong>");
}
```

It will try to find each `@@someWord` and place `someWord` part in group 1. In replacement we are using match stored in group 1 via `$1` and simply surrounding it with `<strong>` tags.

To understand this code you need to know that `replaceAll(regex,replacement)` uses regular expression (regex) to find part which we want to modify, and `replacement` describes how we want to modify it.
In regex `\\w` represents characters in range `a-z` `A-Z` `0-9` and `_`. If you want to include other characters you can create your own character class, or use `\\S` which represents all non-whitespace characters.